# Every divisor of r^2 is the product of two divisors of r - proof?

Tags: math, factors

I recently came across the following statement when I was trying to solve a problem in TopCoder -

> Every divisor of r^2 is the product of two divisors of r

Here, I was able to prove that

> Any product of two divisors of r will always be a divisor for r^2.

But then, I was not able to prove it the other way, ie.

> Any divisor of r^2 will always be a product of two divisors of r.

I tried googling it, but to no avail. So any light on this proof is much appreciated

-Thanks

Comment: Is one a divisor? Can you give the problem page? I'm also fever in TopCoder.

Comment: One is always a divisor, trivially so

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about number theory.

Comment: It seems to be wrong, let r=2 and r^2=4 then 2 is a factor of r^2, but is it a product of two divisor of r=2?

Comment: @fish_ball Well, 2 can be written as 1 * 2 and 1 is a divisor of 2 and 4.

Comment: Oh, I see the Point. It's meaningful, let me think about it.

Comment: It's obvious, but still need to proof..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let *p*<sub>1</sub>, *p*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *p*<sub>n</sub> be the prime factorization of *r*. (Note that the same prime number can appear multiple times in the prime factorization, e.g. it's possible that *p*<sub>1</sub>=2 and *p*<sub>2</sub>=2.)

Then the prime factorization of *r*<sup>2</sup> is *p*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> *p*<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> ... *p*<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>.

Let *d* be a divisor of *r*<sup>2</sup>. Then *d* = *p*<sub>1</sub><sup>i<sub>1</sub></sup>  *p*<sub>2</sub><sup>i<sub>2</sub></sup>  ... *p*<sub>n</sub><sup>i<sub>n</sub></sup> where each i<sub>k</sub> is either 0, 1, or 2.

Let *a* = the product of all *p*<sub>k</sub> where i<sub>k</sub> is 1 or 2, and let *b* = the product of all *p*<sub>k</sub> where i<sub>k</sub> is 2. Then *a* is a divisor of *r*, *b* is a divisor of *r*, and *ab* = *d*, as desired.

Comment: I think this needs a slight edit: if b had a factor d_k^2, it would not divide r. 

From the prime factorization of D, if i_k is 2, split them among a and b

Comment: @Ben b does not have the factor d_k^2, it has the factor d_k if i_k is 2. This is how I split the i_k among a and b.

Comment: I think you should edit and write the prime factorization of r as `d1^k1, d2^k2, ..., dn^kn`

Comment: @ypercube Good point, I'm assuming that the same prime factor can appear multiple times in the list.

Comment: @PeterOlson You answer yourself, but at the same time prevent others from answering as well?  This seems odd.  Is this procedure documented somewhere, maybe in Meta?

Comment: @pentadecagon Even though I thought the question was off-topic, I wanted to be helpful. I can see why this might be awkward though, since it might look like I'm trying to give my own answer a monopoly on the potential upvotes. I'll ask about it on meta.

Comment: @pentadecagon there is no rule that says that you can't vote to close while (or after, or before answering.) Seems weird indeed but they can always remove their answer if they want to. And Peter did not prevent others from answering. There were 5 votes for closing, Peter only voted once.

Comment: @pentadecagon There's a [meta topic discussing this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122638/is-it-ok-to-answer-a-question-that-you-also-vote-to-close) already. I've decided to make this answer community wiki.

Comment: I think you have a minor mistake in the answer. The *"Let a = the product of all pk where ik is 1"* should be *"Let a = the product of all pk where ik is **>=1**"*

Comment: @ypercube It's community wiki, you can edit it as you like.